# Increasing size of buffer based on field in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, buffer

I am using vector data from a CSV file and ArcGIS.

I can use the Geoprocssing tool Buffer just fine, I use these parameters

[image]

and ArcGIS does produce what I want, however it is way to small (my data is extremely varied, lots of low and high numbers).

[image]

I can't seem to figure how I can increase the size of each circle equally?

EDIT: The numbers I am using are observed values, fairly certain they are ratio or at the very least interval. It's how many times a death occurred with-in a certain area during a specific year (the numbers in the second image are the different areas)

Comment: what are those numbers? if they're frequencies you could use graduated symbols rather than buffering the points

Comment: The numbers I am using are observed values, fairly certain they are ratio or at the very least interval. It's how many times a death occurred with-in a certain area during a specific year (the numbers in the second image are the different areas)

Comment: ok, so I would use graduated symbols, set the minimum and maximum size for the symbols and let arcmap sort out the sizes

Comment: Okay, so I've Jerry Rigged a solution. Inside my data set's attribute table, I just created another field called Times10, used the field calculator to set it as the data I wish to buffer and multiplied it by 10. I keep increasing the value until there was decent overlap. I am trying to think if this will affect my analysis (as 109 * 22 >>>>> than 3 * 22).

Comment: I'd follow @Adam suggestion. Create point dataset and use your field for graduated symbols

Answer (score 1):

It's not really correct to use buffers when what you actually want to display is the importance of points. 
So please follow the suggestion of using graduated symbols instead of creating a new layer with areas!

In addition it's much easier to adapt you don't need to create a new layer, add fields and recalculate them each time you want to change the style :)

Comment: Would I be able to use the Intersect analysis tool on the graduate symbols to find the overlap between all the different symbols?

Comment: No,  you couldn't,  but that doesn't seem like a valid analysis of a count of an occurrence.

Comment: Oh, I am trying to find/select/measure the overlap of each buffer zone/graduated symbol.